# Why does C# pattern matching return float for this?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, switch-expression

Here is the source code

```cs
bool v = false;

object x = v switch {
 true => 0.0f,
 false => 100L,
};
```

the pattern match returns different numeric types for the 2 branches, and the values is converted to obejct as base class

I expect it x to be float for true branch, and int for false branch, but the result is, the return value is derived to float

And if the value is boxed in branches, it worked

```
object x = v switch {
 true => 0.0f as object,
 false => 100L as object,
};
```

I can understand the pattern matching as a whole to derive this result, but I consider it a bug, any explanation to help me?

Comment: It’s not a bug. The return type must be the same and the compiler doesn’t care about what you do with the value afterwards. The values within the switch must agree. That’s why you have to cast them yourself if you want them to be something else than what the language rules say they will be.

Answer (score 3):

The switch expression returns exactly one type. [It says here that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#switch-expression):

> The type of the *switch_expression* is the *best common type*
> (§11.6.3.15) of the expressions appearing to the right of the `=>`
> tokens of the *switch_expression_arms* if such a type exists and the
> expression in every arm of the switch expression can be implicitly
> converted to that type.

The "best common type" mechanism is the same one used for (e.g.) initializing implicitly typed arrays:

[image: implicitly typed arrays with mixed types]